# Como enviar valores de forma oculta para o Banco de Dados SQL dentro de formularios com POST

Tags: php, mysql, string, post

Bom dia galera, tenho uma duvida em PHP.
tenho uma pagina no meu site que contem um formulario que envia atravez de post as informações do mesmo para uma pagina de validação que conecta e envia as informações para o banco de dados. Contudo meu site tem uma versão para desktop e uma para mobile e queria cria uma string "$mododeuso" nas duas paginas mas cada uma com um valor diferente para ser passado para a pagina de validação e ser adicionado junto no banco de dados. Tem como fazer isso pelo input do post? Caso não como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: E que valor essa variável iria ter ?

Comment: no caso a pagina da web "computador" e a pagina mobile "mobile"

Comment: seria para gravar no comentario no banco de dados qual plataforma a pessoa usou para enviar o comentario. Minha pagina tem um identificador de mobile, quando abre o index ele faz a verificação e se for mobile ele abre o m.index que traz o site todo estruturado para uma versão mobile

Comment: no caso eu preciso criar a string nas paginas de comentario, Desktop e Mobile, e passar ela para a pagina de verificação que fa a ligação com o sql e grava as informações no banco de dados. Ja esta tudo pronto só queria adicionar essa função de forma "oculta" nos codigos.

Comment: Posso te sugerir usar o **DetectMobileBrowsers**. Ele pode te ajudar a fazer isso com poucas linhas de código em JS ou outras linguagens. http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: Broder, não preciso fazer uma identificação, ja tenho o codigo que faz isso, eu so gostaria de criar uma string em cada pagina para enviar para  o banco de dados, na minha pagina tem um painel de controle onde adm pode ver os comentarios entre outros.

Comment: sem conta que esse codigo só manda para outra pagina quando for identificado o mobile, é quase igua ao codigo que usa pra fazer a identificação do site web e mobile, se quiser dar uma olhada o site em ação http://fraturaexposta.esy.es

Comment: Então na função que você faz a verificação manda um valor para um campo `hidden` no HTML e manda via POST.

Comment: funcionou 100% brow vlw, ta adicionando certinho no banco de dados a informação que eu queria. só pra galera conferir usei no caso "<input type="hidden" name="mododeuso" value="Smartphone">" na pagina mobile e "<input type="hidden" name="mododeuso" value="Computador">" na versão desktop e na pagina de verificação, que é a mesma para as 2 versões, coloquei "$mododeuso= $_POST['mododeuso'];" para pegar a sting e adicionei a informação no banco de dados

Comment: Eu não vou votar para fechar porque entendi o problema (entendo que o AP deseja simplesmente saber como detectar o tipo de cliente - desktop ou mobile - e enviar essa informação juntamente ao formulário). Mas, a pergunta deveria ser editada para ficar ficar direta e clara. Aliás, @FraturaExposta, se você conseguiu resolver seria bom adicionar você mesmo uma resposta para ajudar outros leitores futuros. :)

Comment: Uma resposta eu mesmo para ajudar os futuros leitores? tipo essa acima falando que deu certo e o que fiz para acontecer? ou que que eu poste todos os codigos de uns 3 ou 4 arquivos PHP aqui? juro que não entendi o que vc quis  dizer

Comment: Então para ficar o mais claro possivel, no caso eu tenho um site que possui uma versão Desktop para ser visualizada em computadores e uma versão mobile voltada para smartphones e que trabalham de formas individuais uma da outra. Dentro que cada um contia uma pagina com um FORM para entrar em contato com " a equipe de ADM " da pagina.

Comment: Tinha a ideia inicial de criar uma string ($) em cada pagina com o mesmo nome mas cada uma com valores diferentes ( uma Computador e a outra Smartphone ) que fosse enviados para a pagina de codigos do verificador.php, que teria as informações do banco de dados onde armazenar, o codigo com as funções a se executar no banco de dados e as mensagens de erro ou sucesso, para ser inserida no banco de dados junto com as informações do Formulario.D

Comment: Graças ao @Gumball que deu a dica de usar o hidden eu criei um input que não aparece na pagina com esse valor e com o valor que eu precisava para cada pagina como nesse exemplo:' <input type="hidden" name="mododeuso" value="Computador"> ' para a pagina de computador e '<input type="hidden" name="mododeuso" value="Smartphone">' para smartphones. Na pagina de verificação coloquei uma string para pegar a informação do formulario atravez de POST '$mododeuso = $_POST['mododeuso'];' e enviei essa informação junto com as outras para o banco de dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na função que você faz a verificação manda um valor para um campo tipo `hidden` no HTML e manda via POST para o PHP.

```
<input type="hidden" value="desktop" name="device">
```

### PHP

```
$device = $_POST['device'];
```